# USPS API for tracking shipments in PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, usps

I have a problem. I registered on the USPS website and from there I took user and pass to access their API. But when I try to access the tracking I get as a result a single string of text with all the result without formatting XML

The script that I use is this:

```
    $trackingNumber = $numtrack;
    $url = "http://production.shippingapis.com/shippingAPI.dll";
    $service = "TrackV2";
    $xml = rawurlencode("<TrackRequest USERID='MYIDACCOUNT'><TrackID ID='".$trackingNumber."'></TrackID></TrackRequest>");  
    $request = $url . "?API=" . $service . "&XML=" . $xml;
    // send the POST values to USPS
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // parameters to post

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $response = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
    print_r($result);
    $deliveryStatus = $response->TrackResponse->TrackSummary->Status;
    echo $deliveryStatus;
```

The result I get is

> Your item was delivered in ITALY at 10:51 am on June 5, 2015.Customs
>   clearance processing complete, June 4, 2015, 5:29 pm, ITALYCustoms
>   Clearance, June 4, 2015, 11:20 am, ITALYProcessed Through Sort
>   Facility, June 4, 2015, 11:19 am, ITALYDeparted, June 3, 2015, 7:43
>   am, Milan, ITALYDeparted, June 2, 2015, 3:34 pm, Miami, UNITED
>   STATESArrived, June 2, 2015, 10:05 am, Miami, UNITED STATESProcessed
>   Through Sort Facility, June 1, 2015, 8:07 pm, ISC MIAMI FL
>   (USPS)Arrived at Sort Facility, June 1, 2015, 8:07 pm, ISC MIAMI FL
>   (USPS)Departed USPS Facility, June 1, 2015, 2:40 am, MIAMI, FL
>   33112Arrived at USPS Origin Facility, May 31, 2015, 11:22 am, MIAMI,
>   FL 33112Departed Post Office, May 30, 2015, 4:07 pm, BOCA RATON, FL
>   33431Acceptance, May 30, 2015, 12:27 pm, BOCA RATON, FL
>   33431Pre-Shipment Info Sent to USPS, May 29, 2015

How can I get an XML and then extrapolate individual information I need? I can not jump out.

Answer (score 1):

You have to build your xml response:

Something like this:

```
<?php
/*
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [TrackInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [ID] => CV034836340US ) [TrackSummary] => Your item was delivered in ITALY at 10:51 am on June 5, 2015. [TrackDetail] => Array ( [0] => Customs clearance processing complete, June 4, 2015, 5:29 pm, ITALY [1] => Customs Clearance, June 4, 2015, 11:20 am, ITALY [2] => Processed Through Sort Facility, June 4, 2015, 11:19 am, ITALY... ) ) )
*/
//SIMULATION FROM YOUR OBJECT
$response = (object)array(
'TrackInfo'=>array('ID'=>12342432),
'TrackSummary'=>'Your item was delivered in ITALY at 10:51 am on June 5, 2015.',
'TrackDetail' => array('Customs clearance processing complete, June 4, 2015, 5:29 pm, ITALY','Customs Clearance, June 4, 2015, 11:20 am, ITALY','Processed Through Sort Facility, June 4, 2015, 11:19..., ITALY... ')
);


$string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TrackResponse>
    <TrackInfo>'.(string)$response->TrackInfo['ID'].'</TrackInfo>
    <TrackSummary>'.(string)$response->TrackSummary.'</TrackSummary>
    <TrackDetail>';
    foreach($response->TrackDetail as $detail){
        $string .= '<detail>'.(string)$detail.'</detail>';
    }
$string .='</TrackDetail>
</TrackResponse>';

header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');
echo $string
?>
```

Comment: I have already set the header, but the same I see the result as a continuous string

Comment: have you echo to $result ?

Comment: Yes, the result is the same as `print_r($ result);`

Comment: print_r $response; return this `SimpleXMLElement Object ( [TrackInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [ID] => CV034836340US ) [TrackSummary] => Your item was delivered in ITALY at 10:51 am on June 5, 2015. [TrackDetail] => Array ( [0] => Customs clearance processing complete, June 4, 2015, 5:29 pm, ITALY [1] => Customs Clearance, June 4, 2015, 11:20 am, ITALY [2] => Processed Through Sort Facility, June 4, 2015, 11:19... `

Comment: i suppose that $deliveryStatus have xml format or what show print_r($deliveryStatus)?

Comment: show all complete SimpleXMLElement Object, I don't see the status

Comment: with print_r ($ deliveryStatus) I get the same result as print_r $response;

Comment: As already said in this way the result is SimpleXMLElement Object ( [TrackInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [ID] => CV034836340US ) [TrackSummary] => Your item was delivered in ITALY at 10:51 am on June 5, 2015. [TrackDetail] => Array ( [0] => Customs clearance processing complete, June 4, 2015, 5:29 pm, ITALY [1] => Customs Clearance, June 4, 2015, 11:20 am, ITALY [2] => Processed Through Sort Facility, June 4, 2015, 11:19 am, ITALY... ) ) )

Answer (score 1):

The XML tags are being interpreted by your browser as HTML tags. Escape special characters like `<` with `htmlspecialchars` if you're looking to echo the XML out to the user:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($deliveryStatus);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it would be helpful for someone:

```
$deliveryStatus = $response->TrackInfo->TrackSummary;
echo $deliveryStatus;
```